# Embedding a single object in form

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

I've manage to create a form embedded in another form but I think I'm not doing something right. Here's my code

Category

```
   class Category
    {
        private $id;

        private $name;

        /**
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="category")
         */
        private $subcategorues;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->subcategorues = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        }


        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }

        public function setName($name)
        {
            $this->name = $name;

            return $this;
        }

        public function getName()
        {
            return $this->name;
        }


        public function addSubcategorue(\AppBundle\Entity\Category $subcategorues)
        {
            $this->subcategorues[] = $subcategorues;

            return $this;
        }

        public function removeSubcategorue(\AppBundle\Entity\Category $subcategorues)
        {
            $this->subcategorues->removeElement($subcategorues);
        }

        public function getSubcategorues()
        {
            return $this->subcategorues;
        }

    }
```

Subcategory

```
class Subcategory
{
    private $id;

    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="subcategories")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $category
     */
    public function setCategory($category)
    {
        $this->category = $category;
    }
    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

CategoryType

```
.......
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', 'entity', [
                'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Category',
                'choice_label' => 'name'
            ]);
    }

 public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Category'
    ]);
}
......
```

SubcategoryType

```
 $builder
            ->add('category', new CategoryType(), [
                'label' => false
            ])
            ->add('name', 'text')
            ->add('save', 'submit')
            ;    


  public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Subcategory'
    ]);
}
```

DefaultController

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {

        $subcategory = new Subcategory();

        $form = $this->createForm(new SubcategoryType(), $subcategory);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isValid()){

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $subcategory->setCategory($subcategory->getCategory()->getName());

            $em->persist($subcategory);
            $em->flush();

            return new Response(sprintf('ID %d', $subcategory->getId()));
        }

        return $this->render('AppBundle::layout.html.twig', [
          'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

Please notice this line of code  `$subcategory->setCategory($subcategory->getCategory()->getName())`;
I need that line in order to save the entity to the database otherwise I get an error. So my question is is there a way to skip this line of code and pass category object on the fly to subcategory->category property instead of doing that manually?

//EDIT

Here's the output of dump($form->getData());

```
DefaultController.php on line 33:
Subcategory {#467 ▼
  -id: null
  -name: "Uncharted"
  -category: Category {#588 ▼
    -id: null
    -name: Category {#685 ▼
      -id: 2
      -name: "Games"
      -subcategorues: PersistentCollection {#686 ▶}
    }
    -subcategorues: ArrayCollection {#660 ▶}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `CategoryType` is not correctly mapped compared to your `Category` entity. Actually, in your case, you don't need to have a sub-form `CategoryType` with a `name` field, since you have a `category` field in `SubCategory` which is a relationship towards `Category`.

Just replace:

```
->add('category', new CategoryType(), [
            'label' => false
        ])
```

by:

```
->add('category', 'entity', [
            'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Category',
            'choice_label' => 'name'
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could your try smth like this (for `Category` entity class):

```
public function addSubcategorue(\AppBundle\Entity\Category $subcategorues)
{
    if ($this->subcategorues->contains($subcategorues)) {
        $this->subcategorues->add($subcategorues);
        $subcategorues->setCategory($this);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: For some reason addSubcategorue is never called. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide some info on what is got from form after submission and validation? Smth like output `var_dump($form->getData());`, removing objects, leaving just one string with ClassPath/ClassName. And the options (e.g. setDefaultOptions/ConfigureOptions) method body, maybe not full, I need only `data_class` option, for your category/subcategory form.

Comment: I've updated my original question by adding configureOptions method in *type classes and the dump of form data. Please have a look.

Comment: Looked. Now I don't understand: why do you need that strange string with `$subcategory->setCategory($subcategory->getCategory()->getName())`?)) Could you provide what error you are getting w/o that string. Maybe it is something about cascade persist/merge/update?

Comment: Here's the error if I miss that line of code 

A new entity was found through the relationship 'AppBundle\Entity\Subcategory#category' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: AppBundle\Entity\Category@0000000017424a18000000017b95e21e. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'AppBundle\Entity\Category#__toString()' to get a clue.

Comment: If I add cascade{"persist") it add extra record in category table. Something that I don't want

Comment: First of all use @Sogara 's answer - then most of your problems will be removed, after that add `cascade={"persist", "merge"}` on the `ManyToOne` side.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101766/discussion-between-ilya-yarkovets-and-vodokan).